# paypal indirect payment api - customer asks for the service, our servers calculate the cost and deduct the amount from the customers debit card

Tags: paypal

Following is the flow sequence of the application:
    1. Customer would send sms to our servers containing information about the service subscribed for.
    2. Our servers would extract the account details like account no., Pin no. from the sms and forward it to paypal servers. The forward protocol can be https or any protocol paypal employs at present.
    3. Paypal should send success/fail notification back.
    Do such api service exist in paypal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The availability of the product(s) depend on where your business is located, but yes, PayPal can do this via 'Website Payments Pro' using the DoDirectPayment API.

Note that you would need to record the card details on your side, which raises your PCI compliance level.